# Problems with variable argument list of unknown length

Tags: c, variadic-functions

There is a function my_init(...) that uses a variable argument list. The length of this list is not known, but there is a maximum of 100 and the elements are always char-arrays (means plain C-strings).

That's how I try to decode them:

```
void my_init(...)
{
    va_list vl; 
    int     tagCnt,tagLen=100; 
    char   *listTag,*listValue;

    va_start(vl,tagLen);
    for (tagCnt=0; tagCnt<50; tagCnt++)
    {
        listTag=va_arg(vl,char*);
        if (listTag==0) break;
        listValue=va_arg(vl,char*);

        ... // do some usefult things here
    }
    va_end(vl);
}
```

...and I call this function this way:

```
my_init("tag1","value1",
        "tag2","value2",
        0);
```

So there are always pairs and the end of a list is marked with a 0. Unfortunately my_init() fails, after calling va_start() vl contains some crap that has nothing to do with input parameters and the calls to va_arg() return invalid pointers. So what is wrong in my code?

The code given above is shortened a bit so may be it does not compile...

Thanks!

==================================================================================

EDIT:

I changed code and call this way:

```
void my_init(int dummy,...)
{
    va_list vl; 
    int     tagCnt,tagLen=100; 
    char   *listTag,*listValue;

    va_start(vl,dummy);
    for (tagCnt=0; tagCnt<50; tagCnt++)
    {
        listTag=va_arg(vl,char*);
        if (listTag==0) break;
        listValue=va_arg(vl,char*);

        ... // do some usefult things here
    }
    va_end(vl);
}

my_init(0,
        "tag1","value1",
        "tag2","value2",
        0);
```

Independent from the used header file I now get other crap in my vl, stdargs.h or varargs.h do not make a difference...

Comment: What header file do you include to define va_* macros? Is it stdarg.h? Probably varargs.h can help?

Comment: Did you try to compile without optimization?

Comment: Yes, its a Debug-Build without any optimisations - but that should not have an influence, the release build should work too!?

Comment: Can you produce a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: OK, solved - I used an intermediate step where arglist was handed over to an other function - and this was done in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `va_start` must be the last **named function parameter**.  In other words, the canonical usage is this:

```
void my_func(int arg1, float arg2, ...) {

    va_list vl;

    va_start(vl, arg2);

    // Stuff
}
```

Comment: There is no functional parameter, only the variable list is accepted. So isn't there a way to implement it without?

Comment: @Elmi: Exactly.  You need at least one named parameter.